# (laravel eloquent) get nearest values (tipping game)

Tags: sql, orm, eloquent, laravel-5, nearest-neighbor

I've created a tipping game, users can guess a value and after 12hours the current USD/EUR rate will be taken by API request and the winners which tipped nearest value will win (only one winner, in case n users tipped same amount all of them will win).

How to get the "nearest" tip from database?

```
            foreach ($rounds_closed as $round_closed)
        {
            //get latest rate
            $amount = 458.12;

            //set transaction as processed and set latest rate
            $round_closed->update([
                'status'    => 2,
                'win_tip'   => $amount,

                ]);

            //get lucky winners
    //here I would need eloquent code to choose the "nearest" winners
            $winners_transactions = Transaction::where('round_id', $round_closed->id)->where('assessment', $round_closed->win_tip)->get();

            //if we have at least one winner
            if ($winners_transactions->count() > 0) 
            {
                //calculate their win amount
                $sum = $round_closed->transactions->sum('amount');
                $fee = $sum * 0.10;

                $sum = $sum - $fee;

                $sum = number_format($sum / $winners_transactions->count(), 8, '.', '');

                foreach ($winners_transactions as $winner_transaction)
                {
                    //mark transaction as payed out
                    $winner_transaction->update([
                        'payout'    => 1,
                        ]);

                    //payout user


                }

            }                
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the syntax in your framework, but here is a possible approach in SQL that you could refactor:

```
SET @amount = 458.12;

#Order tips by smallest difference and return the first result
SET @winning_tip = (SELECT tip FROM tips ORDER BY ABS(tip-@amount) ASC LIMIT 1);

#Return all users with the winning tip value 
SELECT userid, tip, ABS(tip-@amount) AS delta FROM tips WHERE tip = @winning_tip
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fac65/2

Depending on the size of your data, you could also pull back all the transactions and code the above logic outside of SQL.

Main thing is you need to determine which tip is closest to the amount and use that as the parameter to select/filter your winners.